# http.host: 0.0.0.0 - ERROR lookup logstash : no such host

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, filebeat

I'm deploying ELK on k8s but getting error on `Filebeat`

`kubectl describe pod filebeat-filebeat-rpjbg -n elk` ///

**Error:**

```
Warning  Unhealthy  8s (x5 over 48s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: logstash: logstash:5044...
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... ERROR lookup logstash on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host
```

In logstash `values.yaml` may be this causing error?

```
logstashConfig:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: 0.0.0.0
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

**PODS:**

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-0    1/1     Running   0          146m
filebeat-filebeat-rpjbg   0/1     Running   0          5m45s
filebeat-filebeat-v4fxz   0/1     Running   0          5m45s
filebeat-filebeat-zf5w7   0/1     Running   0          5m45s
logstash-logstash-0       1/1     Running   0          14m
logstash-logstash-1       1/1     Running   0          14m
logstash-logstash-2       1/1     Running   0          14m
```

**SVC:**

```
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
elasticsearch-master            ClusterIP   10.245.205.251   <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   172m
elasticsearch-master-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   172m
logstash-logstash               ClusterIP   10.245.104.163   <none>        5044/TCP            16m
logstash-logstash-headless      ClusterIP   None             <none>        9600/TCP            16m
```

[elasticsearch - values.yaml](https://github.com/ConorGrocock/DigitalOcean-Kubernetes-Challenge/blob/main/elasticsearch/values.yaml)

[logstash - values.yaml](https://github.com/ConorGrocock/DigitalOcean-Kubernetes-Challenge/blob/main/logstash/values.yaml)

[filebeat - values.yaml](https://github.com/ConorGrocock/DigitalOcean-Kubernetes-Challenge/tree/main/filebeat)

Comment: logstash.yml looks good, the problem looks like a network issue between filebeat and logstash.

Comment: Can you check this one
https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/394#issuecomment-574744508

Comment: @MusabDogan I tried change logstash to the `logstashConfig:
  logstash.yml: |
    hostNetwork: true
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false`  but got error on `logstash Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.0.223:9600/": dial tcp 10.244.0.223:9600: connect: connection refused`

Comment: Try to update filebeat not logstash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filebeat is trying to resolve "logstash", but you don't have a service with that name. You have "logstash-logstash". Try to change filebeat config (line 49 and 116 in filebeat values.yaml) or change the name of your logstash service accordingly.

Comment: Big up man that exaclty solved issue